# There are a lot of questions on onstartups that belong over here

Tags: discussion

They have a [seo tag](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/tagged/seo), and they also have a lot of questions about community management and marketing and topics that would be great for the site. Should we do anything about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag anything over on answers.onstartups that you think is a good question and should be migrated over here.

http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/926/are-questions-related-to-websites-on-topic